# MSBuild: How to get custom generated files after regular build process to be treated as content build output

Tags: msbuild

I'm using MSBuild SDK style projects with VS 2019. I'm trying to run a custom file generation tool which depends on the output of the build of the current project. The files should be treated as if it was regular content for which CopyToOutputDirectory is set. In dependent projects I expect the files to be part of the output directory as well. The solution I now have works, but not from clean builds, which is obviously not acceptable.

I currently have this in the project file:

```xml
    <Target Name="Generation" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
        <Exec Command="GeneratedFiles" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <Content Include="$(TargetDir)\GeneratedFiles.*.xml">
                <TargetPath>GeneratedFiles\%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
                <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            </Content>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

This works, but only for non-clean builds.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `Generation` target doesn't work is because the logic that performs the copies, based on the presence and value of the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata, runs as part of the 'CoreBuild'.  The `Generation` target has `AfterTargets="AfterBuild"`. It runs after the build (and the copying) has already been completed.

The `Generation` target doesn't work for the first build and it doesn't work for subsequent incremental builds either.

The question description says that the files are copied for an incremental build. While it may be true that the files are copied, they can't be getting copied because of the `Generation` target. Without seeing the complete project file, I assume there is another place in the project where the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata is being set for the files.

To have the `Generation` target run after compilation and before files are copied, the following can be used:

```xml
    <Target Name="Generation" AfterTargets="AfterCompile" BeforeTargets="GetCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryItems">
```

The `GetCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryItems` is publicly documented and it runs before another publicly documented target named `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory`. The `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` is defined with a `DependsOnTargets` attribute which runs a set of targets that perform the actually copying. This means that the file copies are completed before the `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` target is completed.

To ensure the correct order, `BeforeTargets="GetCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryItems"` is used and not `BeforeTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory"`.

If the scenario were different and `<Exec Command="GeneratedFiles" />` didn't depend on the compilation step, i.e. the `GeneratedFiles` command didn't use the assembly being created by the project, then the `Generation` target could occur even earlier, e.g.

```xml
    <Target Name="Generation" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
```

### Update - Execute a Target if `ProjectReference` has a specific Project

This update is a response to discussion in the comments.

Let's say we have a FooApp project and a BarLib project and FooApp depends on BarLib and needs to copy arbitrary files from the BarLib project directory.

FooApp has a `ProjectReference` to BarLib, e.g.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BarLib\BarLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

`ProjectReference` is an ItemGroup and we can check if it includes BarLib.

```xml
  <Target Name="CopyFilesFromBar" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- The name of the project to look for -->
      <BarProjectName>BarLib</BarProjectName>
      <!-- Use batching to check the ItemGroup -->
      <!-- Save the project's directory because we will need it later -->
      <BarProjectDirectory Condition="'%(ProjectReference.Filename)' == '$(BarProjectName)'">%(ProjectReference.Directory)</BarProjectDirectory>
      <!-- Set up a boolean that indicates if the project was found or not -->
      <HasProjectRefToBar>false</HasProjectRefToBar>
      <HasProjectRefToBar Condition="$(FooProjectDirectory) != ''">true</HasProjectRefToBar>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Copy if the project was found in ProjectReference -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)$(BarProjectDirectory)\bin\GeneratedFiles\*.*" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)GeneratedFiles" Condition="$(HasProjectRefToBar)" />
  </Target>
```

This target could be defined once in a Directory.Build.targets file and shared across a solution.

If the generated files (in BarLib in the example scenario) don't change based on Configuration and Platform, consider using an output path location that doesn't change as in the example - 'bin\GeneratedFiles'. This makes it much easier for consuming projects. Otherwise keep all the projects in sync with regards to using the same Configuration and Platform values and the same `$(OutputPath)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does clarify some of the problems, but doesn't resolve the issue. To clarify my issue: A project depending on this project would need to generated files as if they are regular output, this is the part that is not working. I generate my output directly to the target directory. The generation needs to load the build output + it's dependencies to be able to generate. Because of this your suggestion doesn't work: after the compilation no files are in the target folder yet and in the obj folder only the compiled file without dependencies is there.

Comment: I tried multiple different versions, but only posted one and think I have mixed the observed behavior, sorry for that. I tried 4 things: 1: Define the itemgroup within target (posted above, but behavior is that no output is copied in dependent project) 2: Define same itemgroup outside of the target (behavior is that output is copied in dependent project for incremental builds) 3&4: Use AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath item type instead of the Content item type in both cases (results in the exact same behavior)

Comment: From the original wording of the question I had no idea that a second project is involved. I assume that the dependent project is using a 'Project Reference'. Is that correct? The 'Project Reference' doesn't bring in all of the files in  the output directory of the  referenced project. The assembly of the referenced project, the first depth of assemblies that are linked to,  and files realated to the assemblies (like .pdb files) are added to the referencing project.

Comment: Regarding ItemGroups within targets and outside targets: When MSBuild loads a project file, all the 'top level' ItemGroups are evaluated but ItemGroups that are within targets are not evaluated until the target runs. This delayed evaluation is important if you want an ItemGroup of files that may not exist before the build runs.

Comment: `Content` is not a type and doesn't impart any special handling. It does not mean the file is 'content' of the build output. It's just a generic catch-all for files that are in the project.

Comment: You could create custom targets that will copy the generated files when the `ProjectReference` ItemGroup includes your project. You could create a package that contains the extra content. You could eliminate the generated files as separate files by embedding them in the assembly.

Comment: I cannot embed it in the assembly as I need the assembly to generate the files. The most viable seems the option to define a custom target for copying the generated files upon ProjectReference, but I don't know how to do that or where to find the documentation for that...

Comment: I added an example of executing a target when `ProjectReference` includes a specific project.